# Mac DNS resolving issues

Tags: network, vpn, dns

After I've installed OpenVPN client I have a problem with DNS resolving. When my Mac is back from sleep DNS doesn't work overall(I actually cant connect to VPN too). Internet is working well, so ping 8.8.8.8 works.

Problem is easily solved manually - go to wifi setting, go to DNS and just press OK. But I little bit tired to do it every time.
Any suggestions how to fix it permanently?

My setup: Mac Pro, chip M1, Ventura 13.5.2